# How to sort Arraylist inside arraylist java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a list inside a list and I am having problem sorting the string timestamp inside the list. Here is the method that retrieves the timestamp in database:

```
public static List<List<String>> getLogs(){
    sql = new String("SELECT EmpID, ValidDate, GROUP_CONCAT(ValidTime) AS logTime FROM logs WHERE Processed = 0 GROUP BY EmpID, ValidDate");
    List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> valDate = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> logs = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        stmt = data.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            id.add(rs.getString("EmpID"));
            valDate.add(String.valueOf(rs.getDate("ValidDate")));
            logs.add(rs.getString("logTime"));
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    values.add(id);
    values.add(valDate);
    values.add(logs);

    return values;
}
```

this is the result:

```
2017-07-22 17:02:00,11:31:00,12:14:00
2017-07-22 11:54:00,11:01:00,17:01:00
2017-07-22 17:01:00,11:30:00,12:29:00
```

It's not in order.

This is how I call this method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.getLogs().get(0).size();i++){
 System.out.println(data.getLogs().get(0).get(i)+" "+data.getLogs().get(1).get(i)+" "+data.getLogs().get(2).get(i));
   }
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at sorting.

Comment: why not do it at SQL level

Comment: Thanks but as you can see to the result the timestamp are not in order 11:31 is after 17:02. I am using it for overtime calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Change your sql to

```
sql = new String("SELECT EmpID, ValidDate, GROUP_CONCAT(ValidTime) AS logTime 
       FROM logs WHERE Processed = 0 GROUP BY EmpID, ValidDate ORDER BY ValidDate");
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < data.getLogs().get(0).size();i++){
 System.out.println(data.getLogs().get(0).get(i)+" "+data.getLogs().get(1).get(i)+" "+data.getLogs().get(2).get(i));
   }` just seems so wrong - it means that you are re-doing the sql 4 times

Comment: Yes, because I am calling every index inside the list.

Comment: **but** every time that  `data.getLogs()` appears in the above code, mweans you are calling that method.  Just call it once and store the value to a variable

Comment: I tried that but I didn't get the values inside the method instead it was giving indexes....

Answer (score 0):

I tried the advise of Ab Sin and search on how to sort data in MySQL and found that its possible to insert ORDER BY inside the GROUP_CONCAT so this is my revised sql statement:

```
SELECT EmpID, 
       ValidDate, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(ValidTime ORDER BY ValidTime ASC) AS logTime 
FROM logs 
WHERE Processed = 0 
GROUP BY EmpID, ValidDate ORDER BY ValidDate ASC
```

Thanks for those who replied and helped me.